# javascript - replace from A to B

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I'm trying to make a chrome extension to replace comments of known trolls in a forum by silence.

is there a way to tell .replace to replace text from a startpoint to an endpoint?
i.e.: replace text starting with 'Name' until 'end of post' by ""

thanks in advance

edit:
to meet the comments:

```
walk(document.body);

function walk(node) 
{
var child, next;

switch ( node.nodeType )  
{
    case 1:  // Element
    case 9:  // Document
    case 11: // Document fragment
        child = node.firstChild;
        while ( child ) 
        {
            next = child.nextSibling;
            walk(child);
            child = next;
        }
        break;

    case 3: // Text node
        handleText(node);
        break;
}
}

function handleText(textNode) 
{
var v = textNode.nodeValue;
var regexReplace = "Name of troll(.*)"

v = v.replace(new RegExp(regexReplace), '');

textNode.nodeValue = v;
}
```

this is what the html looks like:

```
class="up" style="padding-left: 14px" id="pid_31519766" data-pid="31519766"><div class="posting08 ch_wissenschaft"><div class="thread" style="width: 505px" id="t31519766" data-pid="31519766"><div class="row1"><div class="l" style="width:336px "><a class="offset" name="pid31519766"></a><div class="uname" style="max-width:277px "><a rel="nofollow" href="/Userprofil/ByPosting/31519766">NAME OF TROLL</a></div><div class="utools"><a rel="nofollow" class="follow" onclick="STD.FollowingRelationships.followUser(31519766,1363710557719,escape('Orakel von Silesia'))" title="Mitposter von „NAME OF TROLL” werden. „NAME OF TROLL” hat 7 Mitposter.">7</a></div></div><div class="r"><a class="std-button rate p" title="Sehr lesenswert" rel="nofollow" onclick="STD.Forum.rate('31519766',1);">+</a></div><div class="r"><a class="std-button rate n" title="Nicht lesenswert" rel="nofollow" onclick="STD.Forum.rate('31519766', 0);">-</a></div><div class="r rating"><span class="l counter n">14</span><span class="l bar"><span class="wrapper"><span class="n"></span><span class="p"></span></span></span><span class="l counter p">1</span></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="row2"><div class="l date" data-timestamp="11.5.2013 15:08:13"><span class="absolute">11.5.2013, 15:08</span><span class="relative"></span></div><div class="r a"><a rel="nofollow" title="Klicken Sie hier, wenn Sie auf dieses Posting antworten möchten." class="onclick" onclick="STD.Forum.post({action: 'reply', id: '31519766', trigger: this}); return false;">antworten</a></div><div class="r p"><a rel="nofollow" title="Mit diesem Link können Sie die URL des Postings aufrufen." href="/plink/1363710557719/31519766">permalink</a></div><div class="r m"><a rel="nofollow" title="Melden Sie Postings an die Redaktion, wenn diese den Community Richtlinien widersprechen." onclick="STD.Forum.report('31519766');">melden</a></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><div
class="txt" style="width: 505px">
POST I WANNA GET RID OF
</p></div></div></div><div
```

Comment: While I don't think your question should be closed (others have casted close votes) You should really be more precise, put in an example of what you want as an input and what you want out.

Comment: Questions should have the code you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `replace` with a regex:

#### General case ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/buwkJ/)):

```
function escapeRegExp(str) { return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"); }
var A = 'AAA'; // string A
var B = 'BBB'; // string B
var testStr = "BEFORE AAA WILL BE REMOVED BBB AFTER CCC BBB again DDD"; // string to be replaced

var stopAtFirstBMatch = testStr.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(A)+'(.*?)'+escapeRegExp(B)), '');
console.assert(stopAtFirstBMatch == "BEFORE  AFTER CCC BBB again DDD");

var stopAtLastBMatch = testStr.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(A)+'(.*)'+escapeRegExp(B)), '');
console.assert(stopAtLastBMatch == "BEFORE  again DDD");
```

#### Your case ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/veHbF/4/)):

The regex `Name(.*?)end of post` will match anything starting from `'Name'` to the first `'end of post'` it finds. (`(.*?)` is a non-greedy match everything);

In case you mean `end of post` is the actual end  of post, you can use `Name(.*)` as the regex. It will match every text starting with `Name`.

```
var strTest = "Hello my Name is this thal go away until the end of post problem goes away."

var regexEndOfPost = "Name(.*?)end of post"
// alerts: 'Hello my  problem goes away'
alert(strTest.replace(new RegExp(regexEndOfPost), ''));

var regexNameToEnd = "Name(.*)" // in case you want from 'Name' to the end of the string
console.log(strTest.replace(new RegExp(regexNameToEnd), ''));
// alerts: 'Hello my '
alert(strTest.replace(new RegExp(regexNameToEnd), ''));
```

Comment: that actually answers my question - so thanks a lot.

apperantly i asked the wrong question, because that way i can't to what i want to do, because the end of the text i want to replace would be </p> in the html source, but this isn't in the string i read from the text-node.

Comment: @user2112275 Ok, I see you used the second case `"Name(.*)"`. Just as a general advise, the strings used in the regex should be escaped. That is, `var regexReplace = "Name of troll(.*)"` is ok, but if you had a char like `+` or `(`, you had to escape it, like: `var regexReplace = "Name\+ \(of\) troll(.*)";`, kay? Cheers!